# How to draw a large point cloud with a compute shader?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, metal

I'm reading everywhere that I need to use compute shaders to get performant 3d point cloud.
I'm using metal and using the vertex/fragment is slow 20fps for 10 million points on iPhone 12 Pro

I can draw a nice 2d particle system with compute shader, but
how do I use compute shader to draw the depth/3d of a point cloud?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/research/publications/2021/SCHUETZ-2021-PCC/

It appears they are doing with compute shaders - this would definitely require a lot of translation to take it from OpenGL to Metal. They are hitting a (self) reported stable 64 frames per second on a 3090 with 796Mil points. I am unaware of the hardware capabilities for the Pro12 so your mileage may vary.